# How to Select Only Alphanumeric characters from a string in Database DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

How to select only alphanumeric characters from a string in DB2 Database

I am facing a problem with my data, in my data other than alphanumeric characters are there in a column field, where for ***EX*** in Name column: **Ravicￌhandr￢an (￢ￌ￮`)** like these many characters are there. I need a result like Ravichandran. How can i achieve this? Is there any way to remove by query.

I tried `REPLACE`, `TRANSLATE`, `ASCII` functions, but problem in using these functions I am not sure about these unknown characters that what are all there, i have shown above is just example.

My requirement is, other than alphanumeric must be removed. And the Balance string should be the same in a column.

How can i get this done?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some of the attempts that you have made.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , I am trying to select like this: "select upper(replace(translate (column, '^@,???!@#$%^''''&*()_+=￮-{}[]| \/?><,.":;', ''),'ￌ￢ￌ￮`',''  )) as column from XYTABLE"

Answer (score 5):

Use `TRANSLATE(column, '', undesired_characters)` to remove undesired characters from a string.

You don't know, however, which undesired characters exist in your column. But you should know which characters you consider *desired*.

So remove all *desired* characters from the string, which leaves you with the *undesired* characters that occur in it. There you got your undesired characters that you can now remove from the original string:

`TRANSLATE(column, '', TRANSLATE(column, '', desired_characters))`

E.g.:

```
TRANSLATE(column, '', 
  TRANSLATE(column, '', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '))
```

Comment: Hi @Thorsten Kettner, thanks for your reply i tried the following query as you said : select TRANSLATE(column,'',TRANSLATE(column,'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))from table , I am getting error like "SQL0176N  The second, third or fourth argument of the TRANSLATE scalar function is incorrect" What is wrong in this?

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Googling the error code seems to indicate that TRANSLATE has issues with certain collations (variable length vs. fixed length character encodings). I am no DB2 guy and don't know how to solve this myself. Here is a link, however, suggesting that you cast to VARGRAPHIC: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688112. That would be `TRANSLATE(column,'',TRANSLATE(VARGRAPHIC(column),'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklm‌​nopqrstuvwxyz'))from table`. Good luck.